# Static Root - Django version 2.0.1

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, django-staticfiles

Upgraded from Django 1.10 to 2.01.

Settings.py (Has not changed)

```
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = os.path.join('/processor/', 'static/')
```

`python manage.py collectstatic` and `python manage.py runserver` both return the same errors below:

```
hal@hal:~/CSsite$ python manage.py runserver

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Django version 2.0.1, using settings 'CSsite.production'

Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

[ERROR] (Thread-1  ) Internal Server Error: / Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  File "/home/hal/CSsite/processor/views.py", line 108, in index
    return render(request, 'processor/select.html', dic)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.pstaticfilesy", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 106, in render
    url = self.url(context)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 103, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 118, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 215, in inner
    self._setup()

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 494, in _setup
    self._wrapped = get_storage_class(settings.STATICFILES_STORAGE)()

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 379, in __init__
    self.hashed_files = self.load_manifest()

  File "/home/hal/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 401, in load_manifest
    (self.manifest_name, self.manifest_version)) ValueError: Couldn't load manifest 'staticfiles.json' (version 1.0)

[ERROR] (Thread-1  ) "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 27
```

Please advise.

Comment: It seems that the script *couldn't load manifest 'staticfiles.json'*... could you please elaborate more and maybe work on the readability of your question?

Comment: The project worked properly with Django 1.10, then after upgrading  to Django to 2.01 it could no longer find and load manifest staticfiles.json but Settings.py has not changed and paths have not changed so I would like to determine why find  staticfiles.json.

Comment: I am trying to unlock on StackOverflow requirements so I can see responses to my question.